# what are the nodejs datatype equivalent of container datatypes in thrift?

Tags: node.js, thrift

what are the nodejs datatype equivalent of the following thrift datatypes -

```
List
Set 
Map
```

This is my .thrift file.

```
struct Person{
1: required string name_;
2: required map<i64,string> attribute1_;
3: required map<i64,i64> attribute2_;
4: required map<i64,string> attribute3_;
}

service ProcessPerson {  
  void DoPerson(
                1: required list<Person> person_array  
                ) 
}
```

In the nodejs client, while calling the DoPerson method, what should be the datatype for person_array? Is it an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

node.js doesn't add any specialized collection datatypes beyond those which are in javascript: Array and Object. If you are looking for similar functionality to List, Set and Map, I would take a look at [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#collections). It adds convenience methods for iterating, grouping, sorting, filtering, etc.

Yes, the equivalent to your example would be an array of objects:

```
var person  = {
   name: "Kevin Bacon",
   attribute1: {1:"one"},
   attribute2: {1:"two"},
   attribute3: {1:"three"}
};

function DoPerson(prs){
   var person_array = [person];
}
```

The List is an array. The Map is an object and the Set can be:

```
_.uniq(person_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js doesn't over anything over native javascript, though there are modules available that implement the data types you are looking for

- sets: [simplesets](https://github.com/PeterScott/simplesets-nodejs.git)
- lists: [node-linkedlist](https://github.com/kilianc/node-linkedlist.git)